# Is there a "product review" plugin silimar to KissInsights for polls and Disqus for comments?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, plugin

Is there any kind of plugin I could use to enable and monitor product reviews on certain product pages of my website? I like the way KissInsights and Disqus work and would like to use a similar service for reviews.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a bit of more creative searching I've found [Rateback](http://www.citricle.com/products/rateback), a free service from Citricle. Powerreviews also has its own [Customer Reviews](http://www.powerreviews.com/products/social-content-engine/customer-reviews) service, although it's not free and more focused as a service for large enterprises.

Lastly I've also stumbled upon an [opensource review script](http://openreviewscript.org/) that can be used to set up a complete reviewing site.